# Formula not vectorized, error in R

Tags: raster, r, error, function

I have the following `traceback` and I would like some help to understand/solve it. 
Can anyone explain to me what to look here?

```
6: stop("cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized")
5: .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun, 
       ...)
4: .local(x, y, ...)
3: raster::overlay(x, fun = tslp, ...)
2: raster::overlay(x, fun = tslp, ...)
1: raster.kendall(raster_stack, tau = TRUE, intercept = TRUE, p.value = TRUE, 
       z.value = TRUE, confidence = TRUE)
```

example data:

```
dates<-as.data.frame(
  as.Date(c('2010-10-1','2009-5-26','2008-5-10','2007-3-13','2006-2-2')))

rst = raster(matrix(1:15,3,4))
raster_stack = stack(rst,rst,rst,rst,rst)
raster_stack <- setZ(raster_stack, dates[,1], "my_dates")
```

Comment: @Robert Hijmans, I would really appreciate your support on this. I believe that this error relates to the raster package (?).

Comment: What are you doing to generate this error? How can we reproduce this?

Comment: @Spacedman, I am trying to calculate a trend for my raster stack, as it appears on number 1. of the traceback. The raster.Kendall function is from the spatialEco library.  It can be reproduced with any raster stack, I will edit my question.

Comment: Works for me if I run your setup code and then run `raster.kendall(raster_stack, tau = TRUE, intercept = TRUE, p.value = TRUE,z.value = TRUE, confidence = TRUE)` from the last line of your traceback. spatialEco: 1.1.1 and raster: 2.9.5 versions

Comment: @Spacedman thank you for your time. I have the raster version 3.0-2 and spatialEco 1.2-0. Do you know if I can use the versions that you suggest to see if the issue persist? Is it possible to install older versions separately?

Comment: Let me try with those versions first.... one moment please...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug that happens when there's less than 8 layers in your stack. Here's a test function that generates and runs on an ixjxk rows x columns x layers stack:

```
testkendall <-
function(i,j,k){
  raster_stack = do.call(stack, replicate(k, raster(matrix(runif(i*j),i,j))))
  raster.kendall(raster_stack)
}
```

And it works on 23x17x8:

```
> testkendall(23, 17, 8)
Outputting: slope tau intercept p.value z.value LCI UCI 

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 23, 17, 391  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.05882353, 0.04347826  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -0.1246867, 0.1165944  (min, max)
```

But fails on 23x17x7:

```
> testkendall(23, 17, 7)
Outputting: slope tau intercept p.value z.value LCI UCI 

Error in .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun,  : 
  cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

This is because the `kendall` function in `spatialEco` requires 8 or more layers:

```
     kendall(y, tau = TRUE, p.value = TRUE, z.value = TRUE,
       confidence = TRUE, intercept = TRUE, prewhiten = FALSE, na.rm, ...)

Arguments:

       y: A vector representing a timeseries with >= 8 obs
```

Which I suspect is a change since the docs for `raster.kendall` was written, which says 5 layers:

```
     raster.kendall(x, tau = FALSE, intercept = FALSE, p.value = FALSE,
       z.value = FALSE, confidence = FALSE, autocorrelation = FALSE, ...)

Arguments:

       x: A rasterStack object with at least 5 layers
```

Comment: Yes, I do have an error check for < 8 layers that is not reporting. That said, I have had enough issues with erroneous vectorization errors in `raster:overlay` and `raster::calc` that I am splitting out functions like this so that they can be used independently. In the development release of the package, I have the kendall function so that it operates on a vector and can then be passed to `raster::overlay` or used as an apply function on an SpatialPixelsDataFrame object. The raster.kendall function is being changed accordingly.

Comment: BTW, I changed from 5 to 8 minimum observations to facilitate an autocorrelation via prewhitening option. I guess I did not change the documentation or error message, just the function in `spatialEco::kendall'. I am weary of a trend with fewer than 8 obs so, I think that I will leave it there regardless of applying prewhitening. Changed now, thanks.

Comment: Dear both, thank you so much. I do not think that the issue is the number of layers for me, because the actual raster stack that I use has 30 objects. I used the older versions that Spacedman suggested and is working great again. BTW, great package Jeffrey Evans, thank you!