# Error in RGB to HSV conversion in R: "cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized"

Tags: r, error, color, raster-conversion, rgb

I'm trying to convert a bunch of small rgb rasters (3 channels) into hsv rasters using the raster package in R, similar to the suggestion here:
[QGIS - RGB multiband to HSB(HSV?) multiband](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348801/qgis-rgb-multiband-to-hsbhsv-multiband?newreg=2121523a90974eeb9fef632e2d2584bb)

It has worked previously with another raster using the following code:

```
#load as stack 
rgb_stack <- stack(paste0(wd,"/rgb_raster.tif"))
#create brick and turn into hsv
rgb_brick<-brick(rgb_stack) 
hsvbrick <- overlay(rgb_brick,fun=rgb2hsv)
```

But with the new rasters, I keep getting the error

> Error in .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun,  :
> cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized

Apparently, it is not uncommon, also found here: [Formula not vectorized, error in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336735/formula-not-vectorized-error-in-r) but I don't know how to adapt this solution for my problem...

Does anyone know how to solve this, or have another suggestion on how to convert rgb to hsv?

Comment: I'm not certain now that rgb2hsv returns its results in the right format for using in `overlay`, so don't rely on it. Its possible you'll have to write a custom function to fix the output up before `overlay` uses it correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is misleading. This works for me as long as there's no NA (missing) values in the raster.

```
> r = raster(matrix(255*seq(0,1,len=16),4,4))
> g = raster(matrix(255*seq(1,0,len=16),4,4))
> b = raster(t(matrix(255*seq(1,0,len=16),4,4)))
> 
> rgb_stack = stack(r,g,b)
> 
> rgb_brick<-brick(rgb_stack) 
> hsvbrick <- overlay(rgb_brick,fun=rgb2hsv)
>
```

But add one NA value in one layer...

```
> rgb_brick[[1]][1] = NA
> hsvbrick <- overlay(rgb_brick,fun=rgb2hsv)
Error in .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun,  : 
  cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

Which would be because `rgb2hsv` errors if there's NA values in the colour bands:

```
> rgb2hsv(1:3,3:1,1:3)
        [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
h 0.33333333 0.000000000 0.83333333
s 0.66666667 0.000000000 0.66666667
v 0.01176471 0.007843137 0.01176471
> rgb2hsv(1:3,3:1,c(1,2,NA))
Error in if (any(0 > rgb) || any(rgb > 1)) stop("rgb values must be in [0, maxColorValue]") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

There's various possible workaround approaches, such as keeping an NA mask of your input raster, setting the NAs to zero, doing the conversion, the setting the NAs back again, or writing or finding a similar `rgb2hsv` function that does return NA for NA inputs without erroring.

I think this function does the right thing but I've not tested it extensively so please do so, making sure it returns correct HSV for known RGB values, before using seriously:

```
rgb2hsvna = function(r, g, b){
    na = is.na(r) | is.na(g) | is.na(b)
    r[na]=0
    g[na]=0
    b[na]=0
    hsv = rgb2hsv(r, g, b)
    hsv[,na]=c(NA,NA,NA)
    t(hsv)
}
```

Usage should be `out = overlay(brick, fun=rgb2hsvna)`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it  - i tried the new function and get the same error. I looked at the rasters again and wonder if it may have something to do with the shape. The first raster -for which the conversion was successful - had a shape that i think was the same as the extent (i.e. the extent of the raster you would get if you tried to crop a raster without masking).  This new raster has an irregular shape.

Comment: I don't see how the shape matters when applying `overlay`. Its a rectangle any way up. Can you share your data or a subset that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I was able to figure it out with my supervisor - it works if i load all three bands individually and transform them into matrices to be read into the function - and THEN i need to use your adapted function to handle the NA's: "hsv <- rgb2hsvna(r = as.numeric(r.mat), g = as.numeric(g.mat), b = as.numeric(b.mat))" Which seems to be working perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you load in each of the bands? I believe I'm having the same issue as you, and I'm not sure how you got to the step of calling the `rgb2hsvna()` function.